# OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'xx_ent_wiki_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a Python package or a valid path to a data directory

Tags: python, nlp, pycharm, spacy

Hi I already learn ML at windows and try to migrate to ubuntu and learn NLP.I already install spacy and model via terminal and termintal in `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages$` python folder and both of them get

```
   You can now load the package via spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
```

But when I try this code in pycharm which i use intepreter 3.8

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
```

And return me and error like this

```
/usr/bin/python3.8 /home/levi/PycharmProjects/spacy/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/levi/PycharmProjects/spacy/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
  File "/home/levi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 51, in load
    return util.load_model(
  File "/home/levi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 354, in load_model
    raise IOError(Errors.E050.format(name=name))
OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

I already searching In a few solution like [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67579945/need-help-oserror-e050-cant-find-model-en-core-web-trf-it-doesnt-seem) or [this](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/4577) but none of them clear my solution.I also try download Spacy via venv,anaconda in my pycharm but have a same result.How to make pycharm load the model because for my understanding we need download model and spacy by seperate library.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

try this line

!python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm

edit:
i saw wrong error is xx_ent so you have install

!python -m spacy download xx_ent_wiki_sm

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32487216)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by installing, not downloading the package.

`%pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/xx_ent_wiki_sm-3.7.0/xx_ent_wiki_sm-3.7.0.tar.gz`

Replace xx_ent_wiki_sm-3.7.0 with your language model package.

Latest models can be found here: https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/